# C++ Chess Move Validation/Generation on Replit

Tags: c++

I recently made a chess engine in python, but python seems to slow to handle high depth of the minimax algorithm, so I wanted to switch it over to C++. I am using replit for all of this, and in replit python, there is a chess library already given to you. I wanted something similar in C++ and a found a few libraries, but I'm having some issues getting them to work.

For instance, I ran git clone https://github.com/Disservin/chess-library in the shell to try and add this library, but I keep getting back errors.

such as

```
./chess-library/tests/../src/attacks_fwd.hpp:158:12: error: inline variables are a C++17 extension [-Werror,-Wc++17-extensions]
    static inline Magic BishopTable[64] = {};
           ^
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/color.cpp:1:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/include.hpp:35:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/attacks.hpp:7:
./chess-library/tests/../src/piece.hpp:24:39: error: no type named 'string_view' in namespace 'std'
    constexpr explicit PieceType(std::string_view type) : pt(underlying::NONE) {
                                 ~~~~~^
./chess-library/tests/../src/piece.hpp:140:26: error: no type named 'string_view' in namespace 'std'
    constexpr Piece(std::string_view p) : piece(underlying::NONE) {
                    ~~~~~^
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/color.cpp:1:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/include.hpp:35:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/attacks.hpp:11:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/board.hpp:14:
./chess-library/tests/../src/constants.hpp:5:16: error: nested namespace definition is a C++17 extension; define each namespace separately [-Werror,-Wc++17-extensions]
namespace chess::constants {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
                { namespace constants
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/color.cpp:1:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/include.hpp:35:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/attacks.hpp:11:
In file included from ./chess-library/tests/../src/board.hpp:17:
./chess-library/tests/../src/utils.hpp:15:39: error: no member named 'string_view' in namespace 'std'
[[nodiscard]] inline std::vector<std::string_view> splitString(std::string_view string, const char &delimiter) {
                                 ~~~~~^
./chess-library/tests/../src/utils.hpp:15:81: error: unknown type name 'string'; did you mean 'std::string'?
[[nodiscard]] inline std::vector<std::string_view> splitString(std::string_view string, const char &delimiter) {
                                                                                ^~~~~~
                                                                                std::string
/nix/store/1gf2flfqnpqbr1b4p4qz2f72y42bs56r-gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/stringfwd.h:79:33: note: 'std::string' declared here
  typedef basic_string<char>    string;   
                                ^
```

This is just a small fraction of the errors in console.

I am new to C++ and i have no idea what any of this means. Any help or suggestions for what to try is appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: https://replit.com/@BenjaminTrumpy/Blobfish-60

Comment: The code is using features from C++17, but the compiler apparently defaults to an older standard. So you need to add option `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++20`

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to be working properly, but it's probably because i am inexperienced in C++

Comment: It could also be that its replit

Comment: How exactly did you try to compile that library? Because the included CMakeLists.txt very much sets the C++ standard to 17.

Comment: I ran git clone https://github.com/Disservin/chess-library in the shell